# How to change display:none with select an option?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use plain JavaScript. I have a select option with two of . When a yes is selected I want a hidden div to display.

```js
function showDiv() {
  document.getElementById().classList ? 'd-block' : 'd-none';
}
```

```html
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="1" id="yes" name="question" onclick="showDiv()">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="yes">Yes</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="0" id="no" name="question" onclick="showDiv()">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="no">No</label>
</div>

<div id="skillMaster" class="d-none">Test</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp

Comment: Don't refer to w3schools. Use MDN instead.

Comment: getElementById expects one argument (id) , classList will just return a list of applied classes - you need to use .classList.add(class) and classList.remove(class) in your case even better if you have one class like maybe .hidden { display: none; } and use classList.toggle('hidden')

Comment: You didn't include id in 'document.getElementById()'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logic

- Get the selected value with `document.querySelector('input[name="question"]:checked').value` which return the value of selected check box.
- Add `d-block` and remove `d-none` if selected value is `"1"`
- Add `d-none` and remove `d-block` if selected value is `"0"`

**Working Fiddle**

```js
function showDiv() {
  const selectedValue = document.querySelector('input[name="question"]:checked').value;
  const addClass = selectedValue === '1' ? 'd-block' : 'd-none';
  const removeClass = selectedValue === '0' ? 'd-block' : 'd-none';
  document.getElementById('skillMaster').classList.add(addClass);
  document.getElementById('skillMaster').classList.remove(removeClass);
}
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none;
}
.d-block {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="1" id="yes" name="question" onclick="showDiv()">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="yes">
    Yes
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="0" id="no" name="question" onclick="showDiv()">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="no">
    No
  </label>
</div>

<div id="skillMaster" class="d-none">Test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to distringuish the input:

```js
function toggleDiv(input) {
  input ? $("#skillMaster").show() : $("#skillMaster").hide();
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="1" id="yes" name="question" onclick="toggleDiv(true)">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="yes">
        Yes
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="0" id="no" name="question" onclick="toggleDiv(false)">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="no">
        No
    </label>
</div>

<div id="skillMaster" class="d-none">Test</div>
```

Comment: `d-none` and `d-block` are Bootstrap classes. OP has to ensure Bootstrap CSS has been linked in the page.

Comment: @Greedo,  Thanks , I want to use bootstrap codes, How to change `d-none` and `d-block`?

Comment: @DeveloperLaravel you right, i updated to use jQuery / Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

```
function showDiv() {
    var x = document.getElementById("skillMaster");
    if (x.style.display === "none") 
    {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } 
    else
    {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

This would do it, all you need to do is target the element which can be done both by ID and Class. You can also change other style properties if needed.

Regarding the `else` statement, it's purely there for the fact that the function can be called for both 'yes' and 'no' and respectively hide or show the div.